# jQuery calculator: values of buttons won't display inside text screen when I clicked on them

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build my own calculator using HTML,CSS and jQuery. The calculator contains 5 rows of buttons and a textfield for calculator screen.
I have finished the HTML and CSS part, but now comes the real challenge. At first I'm trying to make the values of number buttons to appear in calculator text screen when they're clicked on. I've followed this method located in jQuery API documentation where I replaced *slideUp* with *document.getElementById*.

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {  $( this ).slideUp(); });
```

However it didn't work out for me as planned. Can you please look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you in advance. Here is the whole project: [my first ever javascript calculator](http://cssdeck.com/labs/9aixaldm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `jQuery` library included, then you need to append each number, and also, considering that the `calc-screen` element is an input element you need to append the value of the clicked element using `.value`, instead of `innerHTML`.

Also `$(this).document.getElementById('calc-screen')` will not work and will throw you an error, so it needs to be changed to `document.getElementById('calc-screen')`.

Please see this working **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dhu3Lju4/)** or just run the working snippet below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(".btn-number").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('calc-screen').value += this.value;
  });
});
```

```css
#calc-body,
#calc-screen,
.buttons-row {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 2;
}
#calc-body {
  background-color: #8d9194;
  border: 10px solid #697076;
  border-radius: 55px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#calc-screen {
  background-color: #697076;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Anto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 250px;
}
#first-row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.btn-clear,
.btn-plus-negative,
.btn-divide,
.btn-multiply,
.btn-number,
.btn-minus,
.btn-decimal {
  background-color: #718598;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Anto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.btn-equal {
  background-color: #718598;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Anto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
input[class="btn-number"]:hover {
  background-color: #9cafbd;
}
input[value="C"]:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
input[value="="]:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
#first-row,
#third-row,
#fifth-row {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc-body">
  <input type="text" id="calc-screen" disabled="disabled">
  <!-- end of #calc-screen -->
  <row class="buttons-row" id="first-row">
    <input type="button" class="btn-clear" value="C">
    <input type="button" class="btn-plus-negative" value="+-">
    <input type="button" class="btn-divide" value="%">
    <input type="button" class="btn-multiply" value="x">
  </row>
  <!-- end of .buttons #second-row -->
  <row class="buttons-row" id="second-row">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="7">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="8">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="9">
    <input type="button" class="btn-minus" value="-">
  </row>
  <!-- end of .buttons #second-row -->
  <row class="buttons-row" id="third-row">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="4">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="5">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="6">
    <input type="button" class="btn-minus" value="+">
  </row>
  <!-- end of .buttons #third-row -->
  <row class="buttons-row" id="fourth-row">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="1">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="2">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" value="3">
    <input type="button" class="btn-decimal" value=".">
  </row>
  <!-- end of .buttons #fourth-row -->
  <row class="buttons-row" id="fifth-row">
    <input type="button" class="btn-number" id="zero" value="0">
    <input type="button" class="btn-equal" value="=">
  </row>
  <!-- end of .buttons #fifth-row -->
</div>
<!-- end of calc-body -->
```

Comment: @JustasM, awesome. You're welcome. I'm happy to help. Please don't forget to accept the answer if you consider it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- You didn't import the jquery library.
- `document` can be directly accessed, `$(this).document` will cause an error.
- For `input` element, content should be assigned to `value` instead of `innerHTML`.
- New numbers should be appended to the old value.

Try this:

Prepend `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to HTML section.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery( ".btn-number" ).click(function() {
        document.getElementById('calc-screen').value+=this.value;
    });
});
```